# Selecting a row on a JTable shall automatically select the corresponding row on another table, but it does not work

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listselectionlistener

I have a problem with the selection of rows on my JTable instances.

**This is what I would like to to:**
 
I want to have two equal tables with the same data in the rows. When you select a row on the first table, e g the third row, I also want the third row on the second table to be selected automatically. I have solved this by adding a `ListSelectionListener` to the JTable that updates a class that just hold the selected value. Then that class triggers the other JTable with the selected value from the first.

**What my problem is:**
My problem occurs when the user sorts the rows on one of the tables. Then the view changes, but not the underlying objects in the model, that has the same order as before.

Let´s say the tables looks like this when I start the application:

```
Column_1_header_in_table_1            Column_1_header_in_table_2
   Peter                                    Peter  
   John                                     John
   Steve                                    Steve
```

When selecting the first row in `table 1` (which is Peter), then the row containing Peter shall be selected on `table 2` which is also the first row. 
But if I press the column header on `table 1` so the column is sorted, then the view of that table changes to this:

```
Column_1_header_in_table_1            Column_1_header_in_table_2
   John                                     Peter  
   Steve                                    John
   Peter                                    Steve
```

Now, if I select the **first** row in `table 1` (that is John), the first row in `table 2` will be selected (that is Peter). But I want the row with the same name as in `table 1` to be selected on `table 2`, which is row 2 on `table 2`.

Is there some approach I can use to tackle this problem?

**EDIT**
Ok, I will try to describe my solution with the below code that I have written without an editor, so I may contain some errors. But I just want to show conceptually how it works right now. 
First I have done this interface that the MyTable implements:

```
public interface TableUpdater {
    public void updateTable(int age);
}
```

The PersonHolder class just holds the last selected value and triggers the other table when a new value is selected from the first.

```
public class PersonHolder {
    private static int age;
    private List<TableUpdater> tables = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void subscribe(TableUpdater table){
         tables.add(table);
    }


    public static void setValue(int value){
        age = value;
        for(TableUpdater table : tables) {
            table.updateTable(age);
        } 
    }
    public static int getValue(){
        return age;
    }
}
```

Then we have the Table itself:

```
public class MyTable extends JTable implements TableUpdater {
    public MyTable {
        table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new MySelectionListener());
        PersonHolder.subscribe(this);
    }
...
     @Override
     public void updateTable(int age) {
           this.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(age, age);
     }
     private class MySelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {
           public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
               Person p = (Person)getValueAt(e.getLastIndex(), 0);
               PersonHolder.setValue(p.getAge());
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: I want to see your XxxTableModel, there will be your issue, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame with two JTables and with hardcoded value for XxxTableModel,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use: `javax.swing.JTable.convertRowIndexToModel(int)` to convert the current selection index to a model index value and then, in the other table, convert the model index back to a view index with `javax.swing.JTable.convertRowIndexToView(int)` and set that index as the selected row (this assuming that the model in both tables is the same or is equivalent, otherwise you will have to make a look-up based on values).

Here is an example of what I have in mind (I even shuffled the baseModel of both JTable's and perform an index lookup in the other one):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TestSortedTable {

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<Person> baseModel;

        public MyTableModel(List<Person> baseModel) {
            super();
            this.baseModel = new ArrayList<Person>(baseModel);
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return baseModel.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            switch (column) {
            case 0:
                return "First Name";
            case 1:
                return "Last Name";
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return getPersonAtIndex(rowIndex).getFirstName();
            case 1:
                return getPersonAtIndex(rowIndex).getLastName();
            }
            return null;
        }

        public Person getPersonAtIndex(int rowIndex) {
            return baseModel.get(rowIndex);
        }

        public int getIndexOfPerson(Person person) {
            return baseModel.indexOf(person);
        }

    }

    protected void initUI() {
        List<Person> personModel = new ArrayList<TestSortedTable.Person>();
        personModel.add(new Person("John", "Smith"));
        personModel.add(new Person("Peter", "Donoghan"));
        personModel.add(new Person("Amy", "Peterson"));
        personModel.add(new Person("David", "Anderson"));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestSortedTable.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Collections.shuffle(personModel);
        final MyTableModel table1Model = new MyTableModel(personModel);
        final JTable table1 = new JTable(table1Model);
        table1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        Collections.shuffle(personModel);
        final MyTableModel table2Model = new MyTableModel(personModel);
        final JTable table2 = new JTable(table2Model);
        table2.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        table1.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    return;
                }
                int index = table1.getSelectedRow();
                if (index > -1) {
                    int table1ModelIndex = table1.convertRowIndexToModel(table1.getSelectedRow());
                    Person p = table1Model.getPersonAtIndex(table1ModelIndex);
                    int table2ModelIndex = table2Model.getIndexOfPerson(p);
                    int indexInTable2 = table2.convertRowIndexToView(table2ModelIndex);
                    table2.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(indexInTable2, indexInTable2);
                }
            }
        });
        table2.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                    return;
                }
                int index = table2.getSelectedRow();
                if (index > -1) {
                    int table2ModelIndex = table2.convertRowIndexToModel(table2.getSelectedRow());
                    Person p = table2Model.getPersonAtIndex(table2ModelIndex);
                    int table1ModelIndex = table1Model.getIndexOfPerson(p);
                    int indexInTable1 = table1.convertRowIndexToView(table1ModelIndex);
                    table1.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(indexInTable1, indexInTable1);
                }
            }
        });
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table1), BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table2), BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class Person {
        private final String firstName;
        private final String lastName;

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestSortedTable().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: @mKorbel and here I am with I had in mind (156 lines, could have been shorted for an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) but I guess it illustrates the case)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: The models are not the same, but they are equivalent. Look at my edit above. `Person` is a custom object that is a CellRenderer and a CellEditor and has the property `age`. When selecting the Person object called Peter in the first table, I want the Peter to be selected in the second table even if the sortings are different in the table.

Comment: @Rox see my update as well ;-) I actually created a complete (a bit complex) example that shows how this all works, based on the 2 methods I mentionned at the beginning of my post.

Comment: @Rox doesn't matter, if models are the same or similair or not, post an SSCCE, or use demonstrations by author this answer (+1)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: I tried your SSCCE and it works exaclty how I want it to work!! :-) I will study your example to see if I can do something simlar in my code. Thank you very much for you help!