# JTable + DnD : why is first hovered row after drag row selected?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable

I've got a JTable which supports reordering by dragging and dropping rows. This works fairly well. However, every time a drag is initiated on a given row the first subsequent row which the mouse hovers over gets selected.

Even though it sounds weird, this does not happen if I click on a row (to initiate a drag) and the move the mouse to the right or left (as opposed to up or down). In that case (when moving the mouse to the right or left) the row on which the drag was initiated remains selected.

This behaviour applies to both the java (Metal) l&f as well as the linux (GTK+) l&f.

It it should be of interest, I've provided a [SSCCE](http://snipt.org/zjhai8).

```
package com.tracker.workspace.ui.views.test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.dnd.DnDConstants;
import java.awt.dnd.DragGestureEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DragGestureListener;
import java.awt.dnd.DragSource;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.swing.DropMode;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler.TransferSupport;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Main {

    private final JTable table;

    public Main() {

        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel() {

            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return 5;
            }

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return 5;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int r, int c) {
                return r * c;
            }
        });

        // Set up drag and drop on table.
        DragSource.getDefaultDragSource().createDefaultDragGestureRecognizer(table, DnDConstants.ACTION_MOVE, new DefaultDragToReorderTableGestureListener(table));
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        table.setDragEnabled(true);
        table.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT_ROWS);
        table.setTransferHandler(new DefaultDragToReorderTableTransferHandler(table) {

            public boolean moveRow(int source, int target) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        // Set up frame.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainFrame");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        frame.getContentPane().add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public class DefaultDragToReorderTableGestureListener implements DragGestureListener {

        private final JTable table;
        private final int[] allowedDragColumns;

        public DefaultDragToReorderTableGestureListener(JTable table) {
            this.table = table;
            this.allowedDragColumns = new int[0];
        }

        public DefaultDragToReorderTableGestureListener(JTable table, int[] allowedDragColumns) {
            this.table = table;
            this.allowedDragColumns = allowedDragColumns;
        }

        public void dragGestureRecognized(DragGestureEvent e) {

            boolean canDrag = false;

            //We will only allow people to drag specific columns.
            if (allowedDragColumns.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < allowedDragColumns.length; i++) {
                    if (table.convertColumnIndexToModel(table.columnAtPoint(e.getDragOrigin())) == allowedDragColumns[i]) {
                        canDrag = true;
                    }
                }

            } else {
                canDrag = true;
            }

            if (!canDrag) {
                return;
            }

            // Get source row.
            //int sourceRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(table.getSelectedRow());
            int sourceRow = table.rowAtPoint(e.getDragOrigin().getLocation());
            sourceRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(sourceRow);

            //We will only permit the user to drag rows within the same table,
            //and not to other components. Thus, we do not need to create any
            //transfer object to hold any kind of data.
            e.startDrag(null, new IntegerTransferObject(sourceRow));
        }
    }

    public abstract class DefaultDragToReorderTableTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {

        private final JTable table;
        private final int[] allowedDropColumns;

        public DefaultDragToReorderTableTransferHandler(JTable table) {
            this.table = table;
            this.allowedDropColumns = new int[0];
        }

        public DefaultDragToReorderTableTransferHandler(JTable table, int[] allowedDropColumns) {
            this.table = table;
            this.allowedDropColumns = allowedDropColumns;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support) {

            //Do not allow the user to perform any action which is not a drop action.
            if (!support.isDrop()) {
                return false;
            }

            //Do not allow the user to perform any action which involves a data
            //flavor other that an empty flavor.
            if (!support.getTransferable().isDataFlavorSupported(new DataFlavor(Integer.class, "IntegerTransferObject"))) {
                return false;
            }

            //We will only allow people to drag specific columns.
            boolean canDrop = false;
            if (allowedDropColumns.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < allowedDropColumns.length; i++) {
                    if (table.convertColumnIndexToModel(table.columnAtPoint(support.getDropLocation().getDropPoint())) == allowedDropColumns[i]) {
                        canDrop = true;
                    }
                }

            } else {
                canDrop = true;
            }

            if (!canDrop) {
                return false;
            }

            //Do not allow the user to do any drop action involving data from other components.
            if (support.getComponent() != table) {
                return false;
            }

            // Do not allow drops just above source row or just below source row.
            try {

                // Get source row.
                Integer sourceRow = (Integer) support.getTransferable().getTransferData(new DataFlavor(Integer.class, "IntegerTransferObject"));

                // Get target row.
                int targetRow = table.rowAtPoint(support.getDropLocation().getDropPoint());
                targetRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(targetRow);

                // Validate that drop row is not adjacent to drag row.
                if (targetRow == sourceRow || sourceRow + 1 == targetRow || sourceRow - 1 == targetRow) {
                    return false;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean importData(TransferSupport support) {

            //Validate the drop action.
            if (!canImport(support)) {
                return false;
            }

            try {

                //Get source row.
                Integer sourceRow = (Integer) support.getTransferable().getTransferData(new DataFlavor(Integer.class, "IntegerTransferObject"));

                //Get target row.
                int targetRow = table.rowAtPoint(support.getDropLocation().getDropPoint());
                targetRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel(targetRow);

                //Reorder rows based on the user's gestures.
                return moveRow(sourceRow, targetRow);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns the table which this handler operates on.
         *
         * @return  the <code>JTable</code> which this handler operates on.
         */
        protected JTable getTable() {
            return table;
        }

        /**
         * Moves the row at source position to the target position. This method
         * returns <b>false</b> by default, and is expected to be overridden.
         *
         * @param   source an <code>int</code> being the row which is to be moved.
         * @param   target an <code>int</code> being the row's target position.
         * @return  a <code>boolean</code> indicating wether the move was carried
         *          out successfully.
         */
        public abstract boolean moveRow(int source, int target);
    }

    public class AnonymousSource implements TransferObjectSource {

        public UUID getSourceId() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class IntegerTransferObject extends TransferObject {

        private final int integer;
        private final TransferObjectSource source;

        public IntegerTransferObject(int integer) {
            this.integer = integer;
            this.source = new AnonymousSource();
        }

        public IntegerTransferObject(int integer, TransferObjectSource source) {
            this.integer = integer;
            this.source = source;
        }

        public int getInteger() {
            return integer;
        }

        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            return new DataFlavor[]{new DataFlavor(Integer.class, "IntegerTransferObject")};
        }

        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor dataFlavor) {
            DataFlavor[] dataFlavors = getTransferDataFlavors();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataFlavors.length; i++) {
                if (dataFlavors[i].equals(dataFlavor)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor dataFlavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
            if (isDataFlavorSupported(dataFlavor)) {
                return integer;
            } else {
                throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(dataFlavor);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public TransferObjectSource getSource() {
            return source;
        }
    }

    public abstract class TransferObject implements Transferable, Serializable {

        public abstract TransferObjectSource getSource();

    }    

    public interface TransferObjectSource {

        public UUID getSourceId();

    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of *"I love and hate the selection manager"*

Comment: There are some packages like `com.tracker.utilities` that should not be in an SSCCE. Can you show in J2SE?

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed "issue" with com.tracker.utilities and replaced dependencies with classes in SSCCE.

Comment: +1 nice question, selection is done by Mouse / Key Events, probaly there isn't notifiers in API for clearSelection() after whatever happened, the same for another events (add==insert, remove, ...), question is why, better could be if selection exists, like as catching last selected row and hold this index as local variable, maybe

Comment: I've tried to implement a mouse listener which moves the selection back to the row where the drag was initiated. However, this create an effect which makes the selection to first jump down and then back up (or up and then back down).

Comment: [quite easy, see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14633962/714968) by @Guillaume Polet, how to convert JTables view to Model and back (JTable can be sorter, filtered, column(s) can be removed from view)

Comment: I know how to convert view idx to model idx and back, but I can't "overwrite" the behaviour of first hovered row after drag to be selected.